# Java ternary operator does not compile as a statement

Tags: java

I run a simple example of ternary operator. I wonder why in the second case it doesn't work.

```
class Gun 
{
    public int hit;
}

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gun weapon1=new Gun();
        weapon1.hit=54;
        String es1=new String("You killed him!. Grac!");
        String es2=new String("Ops, you were noticed.");

        System.out.println((weapon1.hit>50 ? es1 : es2)); //this works fine

        weapon1.hit>50 ? System.out.println(es1) : System.out.println(es2); // this doesn't

    }
}
```

After all, the ternary operator is supposed to work similar to if-else statements and this if-else code works just fine:

```
if (weapon1.hit>50)
    System.out.println(es1);
else
    System.out.println(es2);
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement at Test1.main(Test1.java:39)` That's the error I get if I uncomment the `weapon1.hit>50 ? System.out.println(es1) : System.out.println(es2);` line.

Comment: `System.out.println(weapon1.hit > 50 ? es1 : es2);`. Also, please learn how to format your code (just use an IDE; it does it for you) to preserve our sanity.

Comment: By *"doesn't work"* you mean that it **doesn't compile**? Like the string literal that is split over 3 lines won't compile? Because, you know, *"doesn't work"* is a lousy description of a problem, and if you get an error, you should show us the error, so we know for sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @Pshemo So you decided to silently fix one of at least 3 compile errors in that code?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement
 at Test1.main(Test1.java:39)` That's the error I get if I uncomment the `weapon1.hit>50 ? System.out.println(es1) : System.out.println(es2);` line.

Comment: @parsecer paste your errors in the question not here

Comment: @Andreas I tried to limit problems to line with conditional operator (I assumed that printing multi-line string was not related to described problem since OP claims that if-else code works fine). OP still needs to improve his question farther and provide proper error description.

Comment: @parsecer You get that error because ternary operator is an *expression*, not a *statement*.

Comment: @Tunaki Since find of the dup. Man, I couldn't even fathom that this is such a common problem that you can even *find* a dup chain on here. *Sheesh...* Lack of imagination on my part, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The conditional is not simply equivalent to an if-else statement.**

From the [specification for the `Conditional Operator ?`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> The conditional operator has three operand expressions. ? appears between the first and second expressions, and : appears between the second and third expressions.
>
> The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> **It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.**

Comment: You will not even get around to that compile-time error until you fix at least two other errors in that code.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator in Java requires expression while `System.out.println` is a statement.

```
ConditionalExpression:
    ConditionalOrExpression
    ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
```

You can find docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

Comment: You will not even get around to that problem until you fix at least two other errors in that code.

Comment: Which are? The rest compiles just fine.